# How does tf.nn.moments calculate variance?

Tags: tensorflow

Look at the test example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(x, [0])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    m, v = sess.run([mean, variance])
    print(m, v)
```

The output is:

```
[3 4]

[2 2]
```

We want to calculate variance along the axis 0, the first column is [1,3,5], and mean = (1+3+5)/3=3, it is right, the variance = [(1-3)^2+(3-3)^2+(5-3)^2]/3=2.6666, but the output is 2, who can tell me how `tf.nn.moments`  calculates variance?

By the way, view the [API DOC](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/nn/moments), what does `shift` do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `x` is an integer tensor and TensorFlow, instead of forcing a conversion, performs the computation as good as it can without changing the type (so the outputs are also integers). You can pass float numbers in the construction of `x` or specify the `dtype` parameter of [`tf.constant`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant):

```
x = tf.constant([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], dtype=tf.float32)
```

Then you get the expected result:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], dtype=tf.float32)
mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(x, [0])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    m, v = sess.run([mean, variance])
    print(m, v)
>>> [ 3.  4.] [ 2.66666675  2.66666675]
```

About the `shift` parameter, it seems to allow you specify a value to, well, "shift" the input. By shift they mean subtract, so if your input is `[1., 2., 4.]` and you give a `shift` of, say, `2.5`, TensorFlow would first subtract that amount and compute the moments from `[-1.5, 0.5, 1.5]`. In general, it seems safe to just leave it as `None`, which will perform a shift by the mean of the input, but I suppose there may be cases where giving a predetermined shift value (e.g. if you know or have an approximate idea of the mean of the input) may yield better numerical stability.

Comment: But I don't think there will be numerical stability problem, because it divide none zero digit.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Replace the following line with correct data dtype
x = tf.constant([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
# suppose you don't want tensorflow to trim the decimal then use float data type. 
x = tf.constant([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], dtype=tf.float32)

Results: array([ 2.66666675,  2.66666675], dtype=float32)
```

Note: from the original implementation [shift is not used](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L592)

Comment: Could you tell me what parameter `shift` do?

Comment: Funny that shift is not being used in master, it you look at [1.2 version](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py) it seems to be used. So maybe they'll deprecate it or redefine its use...

Comment: I think it may use internally to get rid of numerical stability.